# Jquery Drag and Drop: Drop on the background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag

I want drag the panel menu items But here items is drag.
How to drop on the above background image....

```
   $(".drag-images").draggable({
         revert: 'invalid',
         containment: "#panel-03, #drop",
         stop: function() { $(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');}
    });

    $("#panel-03 img" ).draggable({ stack: "#panel-03 img" });

    $("#drop").droppable({
         greddy: true,
         tolerance: 'touch',
         drop: function(event,ui){
                ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert','true');
         }
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8cxd0tgb/)

Comment: Man First of all correct your fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net does not understand <img src="../../image1.png" />

Comment: Sry...How to add images...

Comment: Give cdn path to your images. Upload them on server and use your server path.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8cxd0tgb/3/

Comment: But Now doesn't drag

Comment: Under 'droppable', change 'greddy' to 'greedy'.

Comment: I couldn't understand what you were trying to do with the .toggle and the extra div, so I just deleted those, an renamed a couple of things and it now, at least, drag and drops. http://jsfiddle.net/8cxd0tgb/4/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some script.

Please add this script to your html and try

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Also from your css

```
#panel-03{
    //  remove all overflows hidden
}
```

remove the overflows and the issue with the image not showing will be fixed as well.

Hope this helps..

Comment: I have updated your fiddle. You need to fix some z-index issue and every thing will be fine. Small images are being dragged and dropped but behind some element due to which they get hidden.